# Canvas algorithm to plot signatures randomly like a signed yearbook?

Tags: html, text, canvas, vector, svg

I'm looking for the best approach to plot multiple signatures randomly on a page like a high school yearbook using Canvas or SVG.  Anyone know of existing algorithms or open source code similar to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look into the following javascript libraries? I've used both of them and they work quite well:
[SignaturePad](http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/) or [jSignature](http://willowsystems.github.io/jSignature/)

Both of the offer a fallback to flash if the browser doesn't support it. We have chosen jSignature since the overall performance on different tablets when drawing new signature was better, but I personally like the style & API of signaturePad better.

You can record the signatures as example on a secured admin page and then just plot them wherever you want them.

**Update**
Since you just want random strings and not really signatures I recommend you'll have a look at [HTML5 Canvas – Arrays and Random text](http://sokerirulla.wordpress.com/2011/10/21/html5-random-text/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Random Text</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

var canvas, ctx;
var quotes = new Array();

var img = new Image();   // Create new img element  

//or you can also use:
//var quotes = [];

function setup(){

    //canvas and context setup
    canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    //create values for the array
    quotes[0]="I";
    quotes[1]="think";
    quotes[2]="you";
    quotes[3]="always";
    quotes[4]="have";
    quotes[5]="regrets";
    //function calls
    setInterval(draw,300);
    window.addEventListener("keydown",checkKeyboard);
}
function draw(){

    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length);
    var randomColor = Math.round(Math.random()*80);

    var randomX = Math.random()*canvas.width;
    var randomY = Math.random()*canvas.height*2-canvas.width/2;
    var randomSize = Math.random()*30+10;

    ctx.fillStyle="rgba(255,255,255,0.8)";
    ctx.font=randomSize+"px Arial Black, Gadget, sans-serif";
    ctx.fillText(quotes[randomIndex],randomX,randomY);
    ctx.lineWidth=1;
    //ctx.strokeText(quotes[randomIndex],randomX,randomY);

}
function checkKeyboard(myEvt){
    if(myEvt.keyCode==13){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="setup()">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600" style="border:1px solid; background:url(bg-hand.jpg)"></canvas>
<p>Press "ENTER" to clear the canvas</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A little, but I'm looking to just rotate and fit the signatures on the page not capture them.

Comment: So how do you capture them? What source are you using?

Comment: Just simple text strings, not actual signatures.  Trying to simulate a highschool yearbook page with names and messages scattered randomly on a page.

Comment: Ah, not actual signatures, just names, sorry for that :-)

Comment: Very cool.  That will definitely get me started in the right direction.  Thanks!